# Google Vision API: Support for negative colors on QRCode detector

Tags: android, google-vision, android-vision

I was working on a QRCode reader within my app using the Vision API. I realized the API can't detect negative colors. My customer has thousand of cards with white QRCodes on a blue background.

Attached is an example of 2 qrcodes. The first works perfectly (default colors). The second one doesn't (white on blue). Some commercial QRCode readers are able to read it but I couldn't discover how they do it.

I really want to avoid using third party libs and apps to do this. So far, I'm using the NEGATIVE effect on the camera. But this is a workaround that I want to avoid too.

Invert the bitmap on the fly is very slow and is out of question.

I read somewhere that detection of negative colors is optional on the QRCode specification and it seems that Google Vision API doesn't support it. Suggestions?

Thank you for your attention.

[QRCode Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7q55.png)

[QRCode Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt8Af.png)

Comment: any update on this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Harish nothing so far. As a workaround I'm using an option to set the negative effect on the camera. This is the fast way to read these negative qrcodes.

Comment: Thank you Nom4d3, I think I'll use ZXing libraries as they seem to be working for both normal & inverted QR codes as my requirement is to scan both types of QR codes.

Comment: Has been a while since my last test with this library. But I'm not sure if they implemented already. I can see an open issue about that.

https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/194

Comment: Hope it can still help you, my answer is attached: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49767546/9112590

Comment: Now you  can scan inverted colors QR with vision API.